# Different in mockito injected web mocks vs using spring web mock api

Tags: java

I am writing some test cases for action and tag classes. I figure out that spring provides mocks for all web interfaces e.g request/response/session etc under org.springframework.mock.web package.

Any idea whats the difference in using these mocks v/s inject mocks using @mock annotation?

Answer (score 1):

The mock classes in Spring have actual functionality. They can, for example, respond to JSP include or redirect requests or they can return you the output of the web code as a string (i.e. what the browser would get).

When using mocks, you have to implement every method call that would be made yourself. This works well for simple cases but web objects like response have a state (for example, the response which the code generates). These often do not like mocking. Or rather you can mock them but at the cost of your test not having access to the code's output.